# Javascript Compiler in .Net giving errors

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, vb.net, compiler-construction

I have the following code:

```
 Dim compiler As ICodeCompiler = New Microsoft.JScript.JScriptCodeProvider().CreateCompiler
      Dim params As New CompilerParameters
      params.GenerateInMemory = True

      Dim res As CompilerResults = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(params, TextBox1.Text.Trim)
      Dim ass As Assembly = res.CompiledAssembly
      Dim instance As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(ass.GetType("Foo"))

      Dim thisMethod As MethodInfo = instance.GetType().GetMethod("FindProxyForURL")
      Dim str(1) As String
      str(0) = ""
      str(1) = ""

MessageBox.Show(thisMethod.Invoke(instance, str))
```

Trying to compiler the folowing JavaScript code:

class Foo {

```
    function FindProxyForURL(url, host) 
        {
            alert('Test')
            return "PROXY myproxy.local:8080";
        }
}
```

And getting an error on -

```
 compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(params, TextBox1.Text.Trim)
```

> {C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\zfwspah4.0.js(4,65)
>   : error JS1135: Variable 'alert' has
>   not been declared}

If i remove the "alert" line it works fine.
I gather this is because alert is a "window" object, so .Net doesn't recognise it. I have tried replacing it with window.alert('')
but still get the same error.

How can i fix this?

Comment: How do you propose executing your compiled javascript? I don't believe there's a way to do that within a web page so access to the window object, alert or otherwise, is redundant.

Comment: You would need to add the implementation of the Alert function to your compiled assembly.

Comment: The "alert()" line isn't terminated with a ";".  I assume that would cause a compilation failure, but it might be just a copy-paste error in your posting, and not the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alert` is a function supplied by some host environments (for instance, browsers have it, but servers probably don't). Changing from `alert` to `window.alert` didn't make any difference because (on a browser) it comes to the same thing. *(`window` is a property of the global object that refers back to the global object. `alert` is a property of the global object that refers to a host-provided function. So `window.alert` is the same as `alert` is the same as `window.window.window.alert`. But I digress...)*

You'll have to use (and probably import, or receive as a function parameter, etc.) whatever mechanism is provided by the host environment in which you're going to run your compiled JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a bit on what's been said.

The `window` object is part of the Domain Object Model of a web browser, strictly speaking it's not a javascript object but merely a javascript interface to a browser object,a proxy if you like. As such, and the DOM reference kind of gives this away, it's specific to the execution domain, i.e. it's only available to a javascript interpreter within a web browser than provides a DOM to it. As `alert` is a method of the `window` object you are rather stuck without the DOM.

As TJ mentions, if you want a pop-up alert window available to your compiled javascript app then you are going to have to implement it for yourself and I'll be honest that I don't know where to start there. It's very much outside the scope of this question.